# RegEx scrape phone number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this program (Python):

```
import re

line = "This is a phone number: (061) - 535555. And this is another: 01 - 4657289, 9846012345"

foundNum = re.search(r'((\(?\d{2,3}\)?\D{0,3}\d{6,10})|\d{10})', line)

print("The phone numbers found are: ", foundNum.groups())
```

I am trying to extract all phone numbers from the 'line' string (might be another block of text), but it is not giving expected results, only one value  (first phone number) repeated twice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `findall` instead of `search`, and also eliminate the nested capture group:

```
foundNum = re.findall(r'(\(?\d{2,3}\)?\D{0,3}\d{6,10}|\d{10})', line)
print("The phone numbers found are: ", foundNum)
```

**Result**:

```
('The phone numbers found are: ', ['(061) - 535555', '01 - 4657289', '9846012345'])
```

`re.search()` searches for ***first*** occurrence of RE pattern within the string, so that's why it's only returning the first match. The expression `re.findall()` returns all the non-overlapping matches of patterns in a string as a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `finditer`.

```
import re

line = "This is a phone number: (061) - 535555. And this is another: 01 - 4657289, 9846012345"

foundNum = re.finditer(r'((\(?\d{2,3}\)?\D{0,3}\d{6,10})|\d{10})', line)
for i in foundNum:
    print(i.group())
```

or `findall`:

```
import re

line = "This is a phone number: (061) - 535555. And this is another: 01 - 4657289, 9846012345"

foundNum = re.findall(r'((\(?\d{2,3}\)?\D{0,3}\d{6,10})|\d{10})', line)
print("The phone numbers found are: ", *foundNum)
```

Comment: (using findall) the use of * is giving output as `The phone numbers found are:  ('(061) - 535555', '(061) - 535555') ('01 - 4657289', '01 - 4657289') ('9846012345', '9846012345')` How do I avoid repeated values?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ([**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yLw9dC/1/)):

```
\(?\d[- \d()]*\d
```

Broken down this says:

```
\(?       # match ( eventually
\d        # match a digit
[- \d()]* # one of "-", "0-9", "(", ")" or " ", zero or more times
\d        # another digit
```

This ensures that there's at least a digit in the beginning and the end.